Flutter Customize Scheme InAppWebview Deeplink
when I try to use a deeplink from my api, my webview blocks it.
here is the process, I call my api
and then I have a redirection to the deeplink
I have modified my androidmanifest and info.plist for custom schemas
Flutter 3.16
flutter_inappwebview: ^5.7.1
url_launcher: ^6.1.2
http: ^0.13.4

qui a rencontré ce type de probléme et comment il la résolu???
